# Вставить значения по условию pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь подставить значения по условию c помощью map(), значения вставляются, но данные которые не нужно изменять меняются на NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   [2345, np.nan, np.nan, 'f', np.nan],
                   [2345, np.nan, np.nan, 'g', np.nan],
                   [6789, 's', 'asd', 'g', 'v']],
                  columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
df['2'] = df['1'].map({2345: '1111111111', 6789:'44444444'})
df['3'] = df['1'].map({2345: '2222222222'})
df['4'] = df['1'].map({2345: '3333333333', 6789: '555555555'})
print(df)
df_final = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   [2345, '1111111111', '2222222222', '3333333333', np.nan],
                   [2345, '1111111111', '2222222222', '3333333333', np.nan],
                   [6789, '44444444', 'asd', '555555555', 'v']],
                  columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
```

Спасибо заранее всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что сначала приравниваете каждый столбец первому, а потом делаете с ним map?

Comment: Да, я уже понял свою ошибку ((( Придется писать все условия вручную через where, но там куча колонок и строк. Может быть стоит попробовать через apply(lambda row: replace_function(row))?

Comment: а откуда у вас данные для маппинга? вы их берете из какой-то структуры или просто вручную прописываете?

Comment: Прописываю вручную. XML файл с которого парсятся данные не имеет некоторых данных, а в учете они требуются ((( Приходиться дописывать их через зависимости, то есть там такая струткура: если индекс == 123, то значения в колонках 1 = х, 2 = у, 3 = z. И таких сцепленных данных куча. Я хотел сделать это все в Excel, но по трудозатратам тоже самое что и через loc прописать выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k, v in {'2': {2345: '1111111111', 6789: '44444444'}, '3': {2345: '2222222222'},
             '4': {2345: '3333333333', 6789: '555555555'}}.items():
    df.loc[idx, k] = df.loc[(idx := df['1'].isin(v.keys())), '1'].replace(v)
print(df)
```

```
      1           2           3           4    5
0  1234           a           b           c    d
1  2345  1111111111  2222222222  3333333333  NaN
2  2345  1111111111  2222222222  3333333333  NaN
3  6789    44444444         asd   555555555    v
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что map() изменяются значения всего столбца, а не только значения, соответствующие указанному условию. Вы можете использовать where() метод в сочетании map(), чтобы изменять только те значения, которые соответствуют указанному условию.

Вот как вы могли бы исправить свой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   [[2345, np.nan, np.nan, 'f', np.nan],
                   [2345, np.nan, np.nan, 'g', np.nan],
                   [6789, 's', 'asd', 'g', 'v']],
                  columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

df['2'] = df['1'].where(df['1'].isin([2345, 6789]), df['1'].map({2345: '1111111111', 6789:'44444444'}))
df['3'] = df['1'].where(df['1'] == 2345, df['1'].map({2345: '2222222222'}))
df['4'] = df['1'].where(df['1'].isin([2345, 6789]), df['1'].map({2345: '3333333333', 6789: '555555555'}))

print(df)
```